# Parsing a file in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, interface, struct

I am stuck in a project that I am working on. Since I have limited C++ knowledge, I would appreciate some help.

I had created a project in C++ in which I had defined many structs. Now I want to use these structs for a different project. I want to be able to get a possible interface for these structs and store it in a file called parse_file.

How can I do this? In my new project, where should I insert the code for creating this interface?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to reuse code between projects?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to do hierarchical design. So I have to just use the data that I had stored in the structs in my new project.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution would be to declare the structs in a header file, and then include this header file in both projects.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response.But the thing is that I already have the structs as separate header files which I have used before. So should I just combine those header files and make it into one header file and use it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with including multiple headers but if you have a large amount of structs and associated functions, interfaces, etc and wish to reuse it consider making a library project to be shared by your other projects.

Comment: Thanks. I will read up on how to go about making a library project.

Comment: @Sista: Please note that creating a library project doesn't obviate the need for header files.  Library projects allow reuse of the implementation files without sharing the source code with other people.